# Download Videos using python from ttdownloader

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib3

Hey guys I need some help, I am trying to download videos from this sitehttps://ttdownloader.com/dl.php?v=YTo0OntzOjk6IndhdGVybWFyayI7YjowO3M6NzoidmlkZW9JZCI7czoxOToiNjkxMjEwNzYyNzY1MjY5NzM1MCI7czozOiJ1aWQiO3M6MzI6Ijk0MTdiOWE3NWU2MmE3MDQ1NjZhYzk0MzJjMThlY2VlIjtzOjQ6InRpbWUiO2k6MTYxMTQ5NzE1ODt9 using python.

this is code I have tried.

```
import requests

url ='''https://ttdownloader.com/dl.php?v=YTo0OntzOjk6IndhdGVybWFyayI7YjowO3M6NzoidmlkZW9JZCI7czoxOToiNjkxMjEwNzYyNzY1MjY5NzM1MCI7czozOiJ1aWQiO3M6MzI6Ijk0MTdiOWE3NWU2MmE3MDQ1NjZhYzk0MzJjMThlY2VlIjtzOjQ6InRpbWUiO2k6MTYxMTQ5NzE1ODt9'''
page = requests.get(url)
with open('output.mp4', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(page.content)
```

But it doesnt work as expected, when i check page.content all I see is b''

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I don't understand how your problem opening a link in your browser relates to the code you have posted.

Comment: I am trying to download the video with that code. But it returns nothing in the html.
So, I looked up the link in my browser and found out, it actually doesnt show the video on the webpage, it just starts downloading. But thats not what I want. I want to be able to download the video using requests

Comment: I dontknow if Im clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

❌ The link that you are using is **NOT** a html page.
❌ Therefore it doesn't return anything as html.

✅ Your link is a media link.
✅ Therefore you must stream it and download it. Something like this:

```
import requests

url = '/your/valid/ttdownloader/url'
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
    with open('ouput.mp4', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
            f.write(chunk)
```

***NOTE:***
The link that you posted in the question is now invalid.
Please try the above code with a newly generated link.

Comment: hey,  thanks this worked, but it takes time, is there any way it could be faster?

Comment: Yes, you can increase the speed, by increasing the value.of the `chunk_size` variable.  
You can try `chunk_size=10240` or `chuck_size=20480`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) to directly save the URL to a file:

```
from urllib import request 

url ='''https://ttdownloader.com/dl.php?v=YTo0OntzOjk6IndhdGVybWFyayI7YjowO3M6NzoidmlkZW9JZCI7czoxOToiNjkxMjEwNzYyNzY1MjY5NzM1MCI7czozOiJ1aWQiO3M6MzI6Ijk0MTdiOWE3NWU2MmE3MDQ1NjZhYzk0MzJjMThlY2VlIjtzOjQ6InRpbWUiO2k6MTYxMTQ5NzE1ODt9'''
request.urlretrieve(url, output.mp4)
```

However, this code gave me a `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` error. It appears that this link is not publicly available without authentication.